# How to get error reason when curl_easy_init fails

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

Is it possible get error code (like `errno`) or error description (like `curl_easy_strerror`) when `curl_easy_init` fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not possible to get the reason. From the source code for version 7.58.0 of the library ...

```
struct Curl_easy *curl_easy_init(void) {
    CURLcode result;
    struct Curl_easy *data;

    // Etc..

    result = Curl_open(&data);
    if (result) {
        DEBUGF(fprintf(stderr, "Error: Curl_open failed\n"));
        return NULL;
    }

    return data;
}
```

As you can see, if `Curl_open(...)` fails, the library just outputs an error and aborts: it doesn't modify any state variables such as `errno` which you can later examine to determine the cause of the failure.

However, if the call is failing for you, it may be because `curl_global_init()` is failing. `curl_easy_init()` calls this automatically if you don't call it yourself beforehand. `curl_global_init()` - unlike
 `curl_easy_init()` - actually does return an error code.

Moral of the story ...
Call `curl_global_init(...)` and check its return value before calling `curl_easy_init()`. Don't rely on `curl_easy_init()` doing it automatically.

This will at least allow you to discern whether `curl_global_init(...)` or `Curl_open()` is failing.

E.g.

```
CURLcode res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
if (res != 0) {
    fprintf("Failed global init ...\n");
    exit(1);
}
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if (!curl) {
    ///
}

// Etc.

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_global_cleanup();
```